# JavaScript - do local class variables get garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory

My question is similar to [Do local variables inside of a loop get garbage collected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720740/do-local-variables-inside-of-a-loop-get-garbage-collected)

I have a class that uses recursion to play a blip sound effect in a typewriter style character dialogue screen:

```
class DialogueBox extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {...
        }
        ...
    }
      

    typeWriter(txt,i,speed=50) {
      if(i==txt.length){
        ...
        return
      }
      else{
          // a blip sound effect plays on every new character typed
          let sfx =  new Audio(speechBlip);
          sfx.play();
          ...
          setTimeout(()=>this.typeWriter(txt,i+1,speed),speed);

      }

    }
```

Note the local variable `let sfx = new Audio(speechBlip)` that is being instantiated multiple times. Will this result in a ton of Audio objects stored in memory that will never be cleaned up?

I'm using this method because I like how it sounds more than creating one Audio() in the constructor and re-setting it to 0 time or only replaying when the file completes playing.

Would this method be a major drag on memory? I tried using the memory panel of dev tools but I am not sure if I am interpreting it correctly and am unsure about how it will scale...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR; yes it will be cleared up

Answer:
There is a chance it might not be cleared. if you ever store that sfx variable for later use ( lets say you add to some form of event, timeout, etc... ) then it will be cleared after that listener is executed.

This is a very very situational problem tho, keep that in mind! If for example you have an event emitter and you attach a function to an `on` event, then that function will not be cleared from memory ( for example ).

Anyway. If that variable is used to just do `sfx.play()`, then it will be cleared from memory.

A small suggestion tho. Why don't you create a class variable lets say: `this.blipSound = new Audio()`, and use `this.blipSound.play()` where you need it, you don't have to set it to null or 0 every time as you suggested, just keep it? That way you won't have to worry about memory leaks, as there will be one instance of the class?

Comment: thanks for the helpful answer! I am not using one instance of the class because if I call `this.blipSound.play()` it'll only re-play once the instance has finished playing and I want the sounds to overlap

Comment: Got it! I was pretty sure there was a reason but didn't hurt to mention it